# Prove that $ A^2=0 \Leftrightarrow \mbox{ Row}A⊥\mbox{Col}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd like to get some help
So I need to prove that when $A^2=0 \Leftrightarrow \mbox{ Row}A⊥\mbox{Col}A$

Linear Algebra, of course.
Thanks

Comment: Just note that $A^2=AA$ and think about how does the product $BC$ of two matrices $B$ and $C$ relate the rows of $B$ to the columns of $C$.

Comment: Closing this is silly, especially with the current hint-style answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ent$_{ij}(A^2)=$ Row$_i(A) \cdot$ Col$_j(A)=0$ if and only if ...?

Comment: A=0, am I right?

Comment: $A^2$ is $0$, so all of its entries is $0$

Comment: Indeed, but still, I don't get what you have posted.

Comment: do you know about the inner product? dot product? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Yes, sir. But still I can't find the "connection" between...

Comment: well ok...with matrix multiplication, to determine an entry in the product matrix, you are basically performing a dot product between a row of the first matrix and a column of the second matrix. What is the significance of a dot product being zero? do you know?

Comment: sir do you mean that: <x,y> =o ---> x⊥y ?

Comment: yes...now you can answer the question?

Comment: I don't get what is this Entij(A2)= Rowi(A)⋅ Colj(A)=0 and how its conected...

Comment: oi...explicitly: entry $(i,j)$ of $A^2$ equals the dot product of row $i$ of $A$ with column $j$ of $A$. Maybe you need to spend some time getting the fundamental concepts solidified in your understanding, before asking the questions here?

Comment: how about using Null in order to prove?